# getting the pk of other model from one model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

## models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bill_no = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Sell(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    total = models.IntegerField()
    vat = models.IntegerField()
```

How do get the customer id from Sell model/object?
like `Sell.objects.get(pk=..)`

Comment: Do you mean you want to get the associated customer's id of a given `Sell` object? If yes, then because you already have a `customer` field on the `Sell` model, you can get via `my_sell_object.customer.pk` (where `my_sell_object` is an instance of `Sell`).

Answer (score 2):

You can get using `foreign key` concept.

Here you can get the `pk` of **Customer** model using customer field of **Sell** model, it will be `customer__pk`.

Similarly `customer_name` you can get by `customer__customer_name` and `address` using `customer__address` and `bill_no` using `customer__bill_no`.

**Note:** Remember it is fieldnameincurrentmodel__othermodelfieldname, it is the **double underscore**.

```
 Sell.objects.get(pk=customer__pk)
```